# broken relations when loading from fixture / yaml in play framework

Tags: jpa, playframework, yaml, fixtures

I have found a problem with the play framework. I could also reproduce it, so here I will show a simplified reproduction szenario.

When starting the play application, I want to read sample data from a yaml file. Therefore, i use the class Fixtures. In the yaml file I have prepared a data structure of objects that stand in relation to each other.

The model classes of the data structure look like this:

```
@Entity
public class Album extends Model{
 public String name;
 @ManyToOne
 public Artist artist;
}
@Entity
public class Artist extends Model{
 public String name;
 @OneToMany(mappedBy="artist")
 public List<Album> albums = new ArrayList<Album>();
}
```

The Job that i use to load the yaml file and control the result looks like this:

```
@OnApplicationStart
public class Bootstrap extends Job {
@Override
public void doJob(){
    Fixtures.deleteAllModels();
    Fixtures.loadModels("sample.yml");
    List<Artist> artists = Artist.findAll();
    for (Artist artist : artists) {
        play.Logger.info(artist.name + " has " + artist.albums.size() + " albums");
    }        
}
}
```

if i use the following structure in my yml file, then it works:

```
Artist(b1):
  name: Nirvana
Artist(b2):
  name: ACDC
Album(a1):
  name: Back in Black
  artist: b2
Album(a2):
  name: Highway to Hell
  artist: b2
Album(a3):
  name: Nevermind
  artist: b1
Album(a4):
  name: Bleach
  artist: b1
```

But if i do it like this, then it will NOT work:

```
Album(a1):
  name: Back in Black
Album(a2):
  name: Highway to Hell
Album(a3):
  name: Nevermind
Album(a4):
  name: Bleach
Artist(b1):
  name: Nirvana
  albums: [a3,a4]
Artist(b2):
  name: ACDC
  albums: [a1,a2]
```

However, the documentation right [here](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.1/yaml) tells us, that the second way should work.

Did I make a mistake in my example code, or is this really a problem with the play framework or JPA?

Comment: not shure.. the order is important.. which error do you get? no entities getting importet? i could see this problem: your adding a Album first, which got a FK to an Artist (which does not exist at that point).. if thats not nullable.. your getting a Persictence exception.

Comment: i am not getting exceptions. the relationship is not set. using the first example will output "Nirvana has 2 Albums / ACDC has 2 albums". But with the second example it says they have "0" albums.

Comment: maybe the persistence exceptions are supressed -> no albums getting imported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, according documentation your second try should not work. Problem lies in concept of *relationship owner*. Only owner side (one referenced by mappedby) is consulted when bidirectional relationship is persisted.

In your case

```
Artist(b1):
  name: Nirvana
  albums: [a3,a4]
```

Operates to following list, which is not owner of relationship:

```
 //owner of this relationship if attribute artist in Album entity.
 @OneToMany(mappedBy="artist")
 public List<Album> albums = new ArrayList<Album>();
```

Your first try uses `artist` field in `Album`. It works, because `artist` is owner of bidirectional relationship between `Album` and `Artist`. Because of same reason also example in documentation that you linked works as well.